# How to evaluate performance across WCF webservices?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I would like to evaluate the performance of the some applications. 
The scenario is that I have the following:

```
Client(WPF application)
         |
         |
         |
         V
   Server 1(WCF)
         |
         |
         |
         V
   Server 2(WCF)
         |
         |
         |
         V
   Server 3(WCF)
```

I own the source code of the above applications, I would like to evaluate some key performance. For example the time used to submit the request, and the time that a function took.

The first approach that came up at my mind is that to use a stopwatch/attribute to log the performance and store in some where. However there will be a lot of code change and difficult to manage.

Are there any handy solution to achieve that? Thanks:)

Comment: If you were hosting your WCF services in IIS you could use Windows Server AppFabric as it has rudimentary timing tools

Answer (score 0):

In the long term it would be useful to have stop watches that measure the response time and are logged with a correlation. You could send it to Application Insights, which represents dependent requests along with the operation making it easy to analyse your requests.

If you want to do this without any change in code, you could analyse your web server logs i.e. IIS logs using tools. I have used the Elastic Stack in the past, which makes it easy to query requests above a certain threshold or visually represent long running requests through Kibana

Answer (score 0):

Use performance monitor using command perfmon.exe. check wcf application under your apppool while adding record dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can log down the time with something representing a service request (e.g service content and time of request), and then do further analysis on the log file.